# Initialize matlab DLL libray in C++ Undefined function checkRequiredMCRProducts

Tags: c++, dll, matlab-compiler

I am calling `Matlab` compiled `DLLs` from `C++` code. I use Matab 2015b for development and Matlab 9.0 as runtime.

The following command was used in a `Windows 10 64-bit` machine to compile Matlab application

`mcc -v  -a .\+ismrmrd -W cpplib:libStdFourier -T link:lib StdFourier.m -d E:\dev\matlab\mfiles\StdFourier`

The DLL call works fine in the development machine. But when I deploy it in another machine which runs on `Windows 7 64-bit` with Runtime 9.0 installed, the library fails to initialise. The runtime initialises successfully and following error occurs at library intialise method `libStdFourierInitialize()`

I use following code for initialising runtime and library:

```
mclmcrInitialize();
const char *rtOptions[3];
rtOptions[0] = "-singleCompThread";
rtOptions[1] = "-logfile";
rtOptions[2] = "matlogfile.txt";

if (!mclInitializeApplication(rtOptions,3))
{
 std::cerr << "Could not initialize the application properly." << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "MCR initialized:" << mclIsMCRInitialized() << std::endl; //Returns true

std::cout << "Initialize libStdFourier" << << std::endl;

/* Call the library intialization routine and make sure that the
library was initialized properly. */
if(!libStdFourierInitialize())
{
  fprintf(stderr,"Could not initialize the library.\n");
}
```

And the error console window
[image]

Code for the header:

```
#ifndef __libStdFourier_h
#define __libStdFourier_h 1

#if defined(__cplusplus) && !defined(mclmcrrt_h) && defined(__linux__)
#  pragma implementation "mclmcrrt.h"
#endif
#include "mclmcrrt.h"
#include "mclcppclass.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
#endif

#if defined(__SUNPRO_CC)
/* Solaris shared libraries use __global, rather than mapfiles
* to define the API exported from a shared library. __global is
* only necessary when building the library -- files including
* this header file to use the library do not need the __global
* declaration; hence the EXPORTING_<library> logic.
*/
#ifdef EXPORTING_libStdFourier
#define PUBLIC_libStdFourier_C_API __global
#else
#define PUBLIC_libStdFourier_C_API /* No import statement needed. */
#endif

#define LIB_libStdFourier_C_API PUBLIC_libStdFourier_C_API

#elif defined(_HPUX_SOURCE)

#ifdef EXPORTING_libStdFourier
#define PUBLIC_libStdFourier_C_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PUBLIC_libStdFourier_C_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#define LIB_libStdFourier_C_API PUBLIC_libStdFourier_C_API

#else

#define LIB_libStdFourier_C_API

#endif

/* This symbol is defined in shared libraries. Define it here
* (to nothing) in case this isn't a shared library. 
*/
#ifndef LIB_libStdFourier_C_API 
#define LIB_libStdFourier_C_API /* No special import/export declaration */
#endif

extern LIB_libStdFourier_C_API 
bool MW_CALL_CONV libStdFourierInitializeWithHandlers(
   mclOutputHandlerFcn error_handler, 
   mclOutputHandlerFcn print_handler);

extern LIB_libStdFourier_C_API 
bool MW_CALL_CONV libStdFourierInitialize(void);

extern LIB_libStdFourier_C_API 
void MW_CALL_CONV libStdFourierTerminate(void);



extern LIB_libStdFourier_C_API 
void MW_CALL_CONV libStdFourierPrintStackTrace(void);

extern LIB_libStdFourier_C_API 
bool MW_CALL_CONV mlxStdFourier(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray    *prhs[]);


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus

/* On Windows, use __declspec to control the exported API */
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__)

#ifdef EXPORTING_libStdFourier
#define PUBLIC_libStdFourier_CPP_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PUBLIC_libStdFourier_CPP_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#define LIB_libStdFourier_CPP_API PUBLIC_libStdFourier_CPP_API

#else

#if !defined(LIB_libStdFourier_CPP_API)
#if defined(LIB_libStdFourier_C_API)
#define LIB_libStdFourier_CPP_API LIB_libStdFourier_C_API
#else
#define LIB_libStdFourier_CPP_API /* empty! */ 
#endif
#endif

#endif

extern LIB_libStdFourier_CPP_API void MW_CALL_CONV StdFourier(int nargout, mwArray& bufferQ, mwArray& imageQ, const mwArray& xmlstr, const mwArray& recon_data);

#endif
#endif
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is `checkRequiredMCRProducts` your function? or standard? I guess you need to export functions from your DLL's interface. It would be better if you could share some information or code from your library interface.

Comment: It is a standard method

Comment: From which DLL or library or header?

Comment: I don't know where `checkRequiredMCRProducts` is defined as a function or variable. I could not find anything related to this in either matlab generated header file or source file. I could see one requiredMCRProducts.txt in matlab compiled folder. But I don't find any connection between this file and error.

Comment: This error occurred when I copied some dlls from matlab installation folder to application build folder. The error is now rectified. Thanks to all.